# Show that pda with limited stack accepts regular languages

Tags: automata, regular-language

So what I have to prove is that pushdown automaton with a limited stack size $k \in N > 0$ describes exactly the regular languages.

[Edit:]

I know that regular languages don't need any memory or stack, so the stack size of the PDA shouldn't matter. I just don't know how to go from here. Maybe one possible way would be showing it for stack size k = 1 and then prove by induction? Would I use a regular language as an example for that?

Comment: So what you have to do to not be ignored, downvoted, and closed is to actually describe what you understand about the problem, what you've tried to do, and where you are stuck. This is not a 'do my homework for me" service.

Comment: I know that regular languages don't need any memory or stack, so the stack size of the pda shouldn't matter. I just don't know how to go from here. Maybe showing it for stack size k = 1 and then prove by induction? Would I use a regular language as an example for that?

Comment: Not in comments. See that "edit" in the lower left? Edit your post and put in everything you can about your own thoughts and efforts. The only help I can offer you is in how to fix you post to get better attention. I do not know the definition of "push down automata", and would have to search to be sure of "regular language".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you need to show here.

1. Every regular language is accepted by a pushdown automaton with stack size $k$. This is trivial, since, as you pointed out, DFAs can do this without a stack at all.
2. Every language accepted by a pushdown automataon $M$ with stack size $k$ is regular. This can be done by constructing a DFA $M'$ that accepts the same language as $M$. For this, consider the set of possible states that $M$ can be in (together with the possible states of the stack). Note that this is finite, and in the DFA, have one corresponding state for every pair of (state of $M$, state of stack). You should be able to figure out the transition function now.